# Generics in functions within an object

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, react-tsx

I define the following interface

```
interface Axis {
  renderTick?: <T>(data: T) => React.ReactNode
}
```

And now I want to make an object that uses that interface.

```
interface CustomData {
  name: string
} 

const renderTick: (data: CustomData) => ReactNode = ({name}: CustomData) => (<>{name}</>)
const axis: Axis = {
  renderTick: renderTick
}
```

I had "Type 'T' is not assignable to type 'CustomData'"  error

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I am stuck at the exact same place with nivo charts

Answer (score 0):

You can use generic.

Try

```
interface Axis<T> {
  renderTick?: (data: T) => React.ReactNode
}

interface CustomData {
  name: string
} 

const renderTick = ({name}: CustomData) => (<>{name}</>)
const axis: Axis<CustomData> = {
  renderTick: renderTick
}
```

Use Axis generic T.